# Foreach loop for Terraform?

Tags: terraform

How can I loop through the following bottom section with my array, replacing the variables with my the key/value pair in the alert?

```
##array

teams = {
processor* = "slack-alert-testing-mytest"
purge-service* = "slack-alert-testing-test"
sync-service* = "slack-alert-testing-friend"
}




## Alert

resource "datadog_monitor" "test" {
name = "[kubernetes] Monitor Kubernetes Failed Pods in Namespaces"
type = "query alert"
query = "min(last_10m):default_zero(sum:kubernetes_state.pod.status_phase{kube_cluster_name:*prod* AND pod_phase NOT IN (running , succeeded) AND namespace:<KEY GOES HERE>} by ###{kube_cluster_name,kube_namespace}) >= 1"
message = <<EOF
More than one pod has not been in the succeeded or running state for more than ten minutes ({{kube_cluster_name.name}} cluster). 
<VALUE GOES HERE>
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `for_each`. When using `for_each` on a `map`, the key will be `each.key` and the value will be `each.value`:

```
##array
locals = {
  teams = {
    "processor*"     = "slack-alert-testing-mytest"
    "purge-service*" = "slack-alert-testing-test"
    "sync-service*"  = "slack-alert-testing-friend"
   }
}




## Alert

resource "datadog_monitor" "test" {
  for_each = local.teams
  name = "[kubernetes] Monitor Kubernetes Failed Pods in Namespaces"
  type = "query alert"
  query = "min(last_10m):default_zero(sum:kubernetes_state.pod.status_phase{kube_cluster_name:*prod* AND pod_phase NOT IN (running , succeeded) AND namespace:${each.key}} by ###{kube_cluster_name,kube_namespace}) >= 1"
  message = <<EOF
More than one pod has not been in the succeeded or running state for more than ten minutes ({{kube_cluster_name.name}} cluster). 
${each.value}
EOF
}
```